# Spring/Thymeleaf Unit test: test does not send value for model correctly

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, thymeleaf

I am writing unit tests for my code. Now I want to test if a value put into the form is correctly saved in the variable in the Controller. Both tests that depend on this model attribute being correct, fail. Because the model exists but stays null, this must mean I'm sending the value from my test the wrong way. How can I have my test include an entered value to test the post method correctly?

The test testPostValueInModel() fails with an AssertionError:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'chosenTemp' does not exist
```

I must note that I'm pretty new to all this, so if anyone has an answer please provide some more code examples and explain what is going wrong so I can learn from my mistakes. Thank you.

Here's my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(InvoerschermController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class InvoerschermTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testCorrectModel() {
        try {
            this.mockMvc.perform(get("/invoer", "20")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("chosenTemp"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPost() {
        try {
            this.mockMvc.perform(post("/invoer", "20")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(view().name("invoerscherm"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostValueInModel() {
        try {
            this.mockMvc.perform(post("/invoer", "20")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("chosenTemp"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
@Controller
public class InvoerschermController {

    private String chosenTemp = "20";
    private static PostgresDatabase database;
    private static Connection connection;

    // Static initializer for the database
    static {
        database = new PostgresDatabase();
        connection = database.connectToDatabase();
    }

    @GetMapping("/invoer")
    public String invoer(Model model) {
        // int newTemp = Integer.parseInt(getChosenTemp());
        chosenTemp = database.getTemperature(connection);
        model.addAttribute("chosenTemp", getChosenTemp());
        return "invoerscherm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/invoer")
    public String addInputTemp(String chosenTemp, Model model) {
        setChosenTemp(chosenTemp);
        model.addAttribute("chosenTemp", getChosenTemp());

        try {
            int newTemp = Integer.parseInt(getChosenTemp());
            database.setTemperature(connection, newTemp);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("Invalid number: " + nfe.getMessage());
        }

        return "invoerscherm";
    }

    public String getChosenTemp() {
        return chosenTemp;
    }

    public void setChosenTemp(String chosenTemp) {
        this.chosenTemp = chosenTemp;
    }
}
```

The Thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:include="fragments/template :: head"></head>
<head>
<title>Smart CV</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav th:replace="fragments/template :: header"></nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Temperatuur instellen</h1>
        </div>

        <form action="#" th:action="@{/invoer}" th:object="${invoerscherm}"
            method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="chosenTemp">Gewenste temperatuur:</label> <input
                    type="text" class="form-control" id="chosenTemp" name="chosenTemp"
                    autocomplete="off" th:value="${chosenTemp}" />
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submitKnop">Stel
                in</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <nav th:replace="fragments/template :: footer"></nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get an exception or does just the test fail? And what fail message do you get?

Comment: Your code is flawed. Never store state in a singleton. You aren't mapping request parameters so there s nothing to map. And you shouldn't get and cache the connection. Your `String chosenTemp` should be annotated with `@RequestParam("chosenTemp")` and you should fix your test to pass in that parameter.

Comment: @72Services I'm getting the exception 'java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'chosenTemp' does not exist'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot/Thymeleaf Unit Test: Model attribute does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644515/spring-boot-thymeleaf-unit-test-model-attribute-does-not-exist)

Comment: Why are you asking this question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644515/spring-boot-thymeleaf-unit-test-model-attribute-does-not-exist

Comment: Because that thread was both dead and I worded my question wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum I put in the RequestParam and changed the start of the test to `this.mockMvc.perform(post("/invoer?20")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(model().attributeExists("chosenTemp"));` and now I get the error `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>`

Comment: I must note that I'm pretty new to all this, so if anyone has an answer please provide some more code examples and explain what is going wrong so I can learn from my mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your controller is flawed. You shouldn't keep local state (try to imagine what happens to the `chosenTemp` field when 3 users submit at the same time as there is only a single instance of the `InvoerschermController`.

Your method argument should be annotated with `@RequestParam("chosenTemp")` to match the form you are sending. Your test should also reflect the fact that you are sending a parameter named `chosenTemp`.

First your controller

```
@Controller
public class InvoerschermController {

    private static PostgresDatabase database;
    private static Connection connection;

    // Static initializer for the database
    static {
        database = new PostgresDatabase();
        connection = database.connectToDatabase();
    }

    @GetMapping("/invoer")
    public String invoer(Model model) {
        Integer chosenTemp = database.getTemperature(connection);
        model.addAttribute("chosenTemp", chosenTemp);
        return "invoerscherm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/invoer")
    public String addInputTemp(@RequestParam("chosenTemp") Integer chosenTemp, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("chosenTemp", chosenTemp);
            database.setTemperature(connection, chosenTemp);
        return "invoerscherm";
    }
}
```

Notice the type change from `String` to `Integer` Spring will do the type conversion for you and notice the addition of the `@RequestParam`. Now your test should also reflect this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(InvoerschermController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class InvoerschermTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testCorrectModel() {
        try {
            this.mockMvc.perform(get("/invoer")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("chosenTemp"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPost() {
        try {
            this.mockMvc.perform(post("/invoer").param("chosenTemp", "20").andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(view().name("invoerscherm"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostValueInModel() {
        try {
            this.mockMvc.perform(post("/invoer").param("chosenTemp", "20")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("chosenTemp"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the addition of `.param("chosenTemp", "20")` to add a request parameter with that name.

Your controller is still flawed imho as it shouldn't care about the `Connection` that should all be encapsulated in your `Database` class. Although your test now probably works your actual application will still fail due to the use of Thymeleaf and form binding. The form binding expects an object under the key `invoerScherm` to be available and that object should have a property named `chosenTemp`. You are actually lacking a form object. So what your controller should actually look like.

First you need a form object:

```
public class InvoerScherm {
    private Integer chosenTemp;
    public InvoerScherm() {}
    public InvoerScherm(Integer temp) { this.chosenTemp=temp;}
    // Here be getters/setters
}
```

Then let your controller create and use it

```
@Controller
public class InvoerschermController {

    private static PostgresDatabase database;
    private static Connection connection;

    // Static initializer for the database
    static {
        database = new PostgresDatabase();
        connection = database.connectToDatabase();
    }

    @GetMapping("/invoer")
    public String invoer(Model model) {
        Integer chosenTemp = database.getTemperature(connection);
        InvoerScherm invoerScherm = new InvoerScherm(chosenTemp);
        model.addAttribute("invoerScherm", invoerScherm);
        return "invoerscherm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/invoer")
    public String addInputTemp(@ModelAttribute InvoerScherm invoerScherm, Model model) {
            database.setTemperature(connection, invoerScherm.getChosenTemp());
        return "invoerscherm";
    }
}
```

Ofcourse now your test will fail again, but I leave that task to you.